# Answering 'Amen' to Birkas Kohanim during regular Shemonei Esrei (Chabad Nusach)

Tags: halacha, shacharis-morning-prayer, birchas-kohanim, amen, nusach-ari

Can one answer 'Amen' to Birkas Kohanim when in the middle of Psukei Zemira of Shacharis, and the Tzibbur has already reached repetition of Shemonei Esrei?

There is a permitted-interruption guide in the back of siddur which does permit answering "Amen" to most blessings but the question is whether Birkas Kohanim is in the category of 'most blessings'.

I am referring to the daily weekday or Shabbos Shacharis, when Birkas Kohanim is said by the leader and not the Kohanim.

Comment: I realize it's not necessarily indicative, but _birkas kohanim_ is one of the very few _b'rachos_ mandated by the _Torah_, so one might expect it to be included in "most blessings" whose recitation calls for interruption. Also, I believe there is a note on Rav Soloveitchik's practice regarding responding to _birkas kohanim_ in general in the Koren (Soloveitchik) _machzor_.

Comment: I believe that one interrupts even one's own amidah to respond to bircat Kohanim, including when the accepted response is "kein y'hi ratzon" (most nuschaot).

Answer (score 1):

According to a more detailed chart found on the back of a Chabad siddur, one does not answer the "birkat kohanim" of the chazan during Pesukei Dezimra, but as you can see below, one does answer a real birkat kohanim:

[image]